# Getting a Function Expected error while using array.includes in a if statement

Tags: javascript

i am not sure why i get the Function Expected error and not yielding in useful info while searching the web. Thanks for your time!

```
oCollectedValue =new Array();
var i = 0
for (i; i < CollectedValue.length; i++)
{
    if (Attribute.includes(CollectedValue[i]))
    {
        oCollectedValue.push(CollectedValue[i])
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you share the error message?, it makes it easier to help.

Comment: It would be helpful to see where `Attribute` and `CollectedValue` are defined.

Comment: I am using this code within a software program with it own code writer that can use passed inputs as declared variables. CollectedValue and Attribute are both array/list type inputs.

Comment: What browser does throw that?

Comment: As far as the error goes all i am getting is error text 'Function Expected'. there is not a error # returned. Thanks!

Comment: The program i am using is being used for dev on all major browsers. I usually run the program on Chrome.

Comment: Can you `console.log(CollectedValue)` and `console.log(Attribute)` then share the log , please. We need to see what value are defined there so we can help

Comment: I would recommend you to console.log reference that throws it. This error usually occurs when you are calling function on property or Object, but not a function reference.

Comment: @TahaAzzabi //CollectedValue ["YES", "NO", "TEST", "YES", "NO"]

Comment: @TahaAzzabi //Attribute ["YES", "NO"]

Comment: @bigless that very well could be it. How can i do it differently?

Comment: [It works fine on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o0cqyw4j/) using your code and the arrays you’ve given. Are you maybe running it on an old browser that doesn’t support `includes`? [It’s somewhat modern.](https://www.caniuse.com/#feat=array-includes) (By the way, you can say `var oCollectedValue = []` rather than `new Array`, and you can put the `var i = 0` in the first part of the `for` loop, like `for (var i = 0;`.)

Comment: as @Aankhen said it's work fine i even test your code on JsFiddle

Comment: @Aankhen@TahaAzzabi I see that there could be compatibility issues with IE11 and thats most probably why i am seeing what i am seeing. Is there a more medieval way of doing this?

Comment: I've found a problem, but for exact solution you should provide some more code of your own. Check my answer below

Comment: Instead of using `Attribute` as an array, make it an object `Attribute= { "Yes" : true, "No": true};` Then a simple fast test `if (Attribute[CollectedValue[i]])` prevents a linear search in the list.

Comment: @Braca  i ended up working around the problem and taking a very rudimentary approach. Checkout my solution in answers below. Appreciate everyone taking the time to help! you all rock!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[If you can rely on IE9+](https://www.caniuse.com/#feat=es5), you can use `indexOf` instead of `includes`:

```js
const CollectedValue = ["YES", "NO", "TEST", "YES", "NO"];
const Attribute = ["YES", "NO"];

oCollectedValue =new Array();
var i = 0
for (i; i < CollectedValue.length; i++)
{
    if (Attribute.indexOf(CollectedValue[i]) > -1)
    {
        oCollectedValue.push(CollectedValue[i])
    }
} 

console.log(oCollectedValue);
```

Comment: that is another good way to handle this. my program for some reason doesn't want to accept that either. i think there might be a underlying problem that i am not able to see. Thanks for your help with this!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not in the code you've got here, it's in the code *around* it. The error *'Function Expected'* means that the code that's calling your code expects to get a function back, but your code returns a value. You should return a function instead. Here's an example:

```js
CollectedValue = ["YES", "NO", "TEST", "YES", "NO"];
Attribute = ["YES", "NO"];


function getFuncCollectedValue(){
    function getCollectedValue(Attribute, CollectedValue) {
        oCollectedValue = [];
        var i = 0;
        for (var i; i < CollectedValue.length; i++) {
            if (Attribute.indexOf(CollectedValue[i]) > -1) { // correction by Aankhen
                oCollectedValue.push(CollectedValue[i]);
            }
        }
        return oCollectedValue;
    }
    return getCollectedValue;
}

console.log("In next line we get function as return value:");
console.log(getFuncCollectedValue()); // Returns a function, that's what your code expects

// We can now call returned function like this
console.log("Now we are calling returned function:");
console.log(getFuncCollectedValue()(Attribute, CollectedValue));
```

If this all seems unfamiliar look up 'functions returning functions'.

Comment: thanks Braca. i see what you are saying here. This is very good info. I appreciate you taking the time. I ended up strong-arming the code and taking a medieval approach to get around the issue i was having. Checkout my answer below. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

i guess the compiler i am using is not registering the use of a function or straight up use of a method. so to get around all that i had to structure my code the following way which resolved the issue i was having. Hope this helps someone out there.

```
oCollectedValue = [];
oCreatedOn = [];
var x = 0

for (x; x < Attribute.length; x++)
{
        for (var i = 0; i < CollectedValue.length; i++) 
        {
            if (Attribute[x] === CollectedValue[i]) 
            { 
                oCollectedValue.push(CollectedValue[i]);
                oCreatedOn.push(CreatedOn[i]);
            }
        }
}
```